# Stop Qt from translating dynamic properties

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using Qt 5.6.0.

I have a `ui` form that is retranslated on language change.
In Creator and inside the designer section I added a dynamic property with the string `"style"`.

This dynamic property is responsible for setting the correct style-sheet for the `pushButton`. The problem is that, when I change the language, my dynamic property and associated style-sheet don't work.

I also found out that the function `retranslateUi()` is executed on language change which has the following statement:

```
pushButton->setProperty(
    "style",
    QVariant(
        QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "button", 0)
    )
);
```

The question is that what can I do to stop Qt from putting `QApplication::translate()` inside the generated `ui_classname.h` file.

OR, 
if the `QApplication::translate()` is not the cause, then how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you created the form in a Designer, you need to uncheck the "translatable" checkbox on each instance of the property in the Property Editor dock:

> [image: 'translatable' checkbox]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. but I really need the button's `text` to be translated but not the `dynamic property` .

Comment: That's not a problem - each property has its own 'translatable' checkbox, so you check the one under the `text` property, but not the one under your dynamic property

Comment: I've updated the image to show both the `text` and `role` properties